# Mongoose typings, id property not available

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, typescript-typings

I used the following code for my mongoose TypeScript model.

```
import mongoose = require('mongoose')

export interface PieceInterface extends mongoose.Document {
  date: Date
  summary: string
  source: string
  link: string
}

export const PieceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  date: { type: Date, default: new Date(), required: true },
  summary: { type: String, default: 'summary', required: true },
  source: { type: String, default: 'source', required: true },
  link: { type: String, default: '#', required: true }
})

export const Piece = mongoose.model<PieceInterface>('Piece', PieceSchema)
```

Now, when I use `Piece.find({}).then(x => {...})`, `x` is a `Promise<PieceInterface[]>` as expected.

However, I am not able to get

```
Piece.find({}).then(x => {
  console.log(x[0].id)
})
```

to compile properly, it always tells me `error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'PieceInterface'`.

Since, `PieceInterface` extends `mongoose.Document`, I looked...

```
interface Document extends MongooseDocument, NodeJS.EventEmitter, ModelProperties
```

And then,

```
class MongooseDocument implements MongooseDocumentOptionals
```

And finally this,

```
interface MongooseDocumentOptionals {
  id?: string;
}
```

And in my mind, it should work. I am able to use variables provided by `MongooseDocument` and `ModelProperties`, but not `MongooseDocumentOptionals`.

Anything I'm missing?

References: `mongoose.d.ts` from GitHub

[Definition of `document`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/types-2.0/mongoose/index.d.ts#L2500)

[Definition of `MongooseDocument`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/types-2.0/mongoose/index.d.ts#L892)

[Definition of `MongooseDocumentOptionals`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/types-2.0/mongoose/index.d.ts#L1055)

Answer (score 0):

Default field name for the ID in Mongo is `_id` not `id`, so you should do:

```
Piece.find({}).then(x => {
  console.log(x[0]._id)
})
```

Comment: But mongoose by default has a virtual `id` getter, I think that's why the type definition of `MongooseDocumentOptional` includes `id`.

Answer (score 0):

my friend,

Use this mechanism,

```
import mongoose = require('mongoose')

export interface PieceInterface extends mongoose.Document {
  id : mongoose.Types.ObjectId //Add this line
  date: Date
  summary: string
  source: string
  link: string
}

export const PieceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  date: { type: Date, default: new Date(), required: true },
  summary: { type: String, default: 'summary', required: true },
  source: { type: String, default: 'source', required: true },
  link: { type: String, default: '#', required: true }
})

export const Piece = mongoose.model<PieceInterface>('Piece', PieceSchema)
```